# Create editionable view on Oracle

Tags: oracle, view

I am trying to create an ORACLE EDITIONABLE VIEW but I am getting the error:

SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "SCHEMA"."TABLE" ....
```

In https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504 is mentioned how u can create this kind of view.

If I remove EDITIONABLE the view is created without a problem.

Some advice will be welcomed :-)

Comment: Post reproducible example. Check the restrictions for `EDITIONED` [views](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF54763)

Comment: and of course post your Oracle version:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong syntax prbly

```
CREATE EDITIONING VIEW
```

You need oracle 11gR2 or higher

Also you need to enable Editions for user: ([from here)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/edition-based-redefinition-11gr2#enabling_editions_for_a_user)

*Enabling editions for a user is done using the ALTER USER command. **This is not reversible**. The result of this command can be seen by querying the EDITIONS_ENABLED column of the DBA_USERS view.*

```
CONN / AS SYSDBA

ALTER USER edition_test ENABLE EDITIONS;
```