# Editionable or editing view

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I'm using an Oracle database (11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0).

on have a view which declaration starts like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "BLABLA_NEW"
```

and I'm getting the error:

```
SQL-Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

If I replace the view declaration with

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
```

the view is created.

On sys I have ran the follwing statements

```
ALTER USER My_USER ENABLE EDITIONS;

grant create any edition to My_USER
```

Even when replacing EDITIONABLE with EDITIONING the view is not created.
Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create editionable view on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197822/create-editionable-view-on-oracle)

Comment: Can you provide mvce of the view DDL? Are the dependent objects associated with this view EBR objects (e.g. synonyms of the editioning views which are associated with a table)?

Comment: can you please tell me what is mvce?

Answer (score 1):

The command is `CREATE EDITIONING VIEW` in Oracle 11gR2 or higher

Comment: I have tried also CREATE EDITIONING VIEW, without success.

Comment: make sure you have privelege